# Flow type: dynamically get a Class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, flowtype

Is there a way of getting a dynamic class method? I'm getting the error `Cannot get (...) because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in ...`.

Here is a [Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8wBhOXOAOzI+IF8wo+NmADk+SjREBudKiowKAZ0VgAKmUXEyAD0LcAJitbsuPADwUOATwB8jdGDBYyhABZx9ARjABeMAAoASgAuADc4DH1fOwZeGUdnNw8AJl8AkPDI6MY41ASXd30AZjSgsIionxjc-KT9ABZSjIrs2PinAo8AVibyrKqcmTywAHMXPXxSxMKAOQBXLAAjMnxgsA4F5fxA1uGASCpOTQ66tLcMRQBtAANpjwASBjv9eaWV3muAXXbawqD23jDVCAoA) example.

Comment: No. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1323#issuecomment-509401288

There are certainly ways to work around this, but the short answer is no, there is no actual way to index class properties in flow.

Comment: Is something like this sufficient for what you want? https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8wBhOXOAOzI+IF8wo+NmADk+SjREBudFRgUAzgrAAVMguJkAHoW4ATZa3ZceAHgocAngD5G6MGCxlCACzh6AjGAC8YABQAlABcAG5wGHo+tgy8Mg5Oru4ATD7+wWERUYyxqPHObnoAzKmBoeGR3tE5eYl6ACwl6eVZMXGO+e4ArI1lmZXZMrlgAObOuvglCQUAcgCuWABGZPhBYF4APmApm8WbDZudwWAZFdFDAJBUnBrttSWuGAqrFpYBANoABlPuACQM33o5otlrwPgBdNo1AqBNq8VBwoA

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's perfect! Many thanks!